# When I click a color, my program goes to windows bar

Tags: vb.net, colors, reduce

I made a vb.net program . All were ok but i realized that when i click a textbox or button or whatever which color is red, the program reduces (as is i clicked on _ near the X to close the program)
so, for exemple, when I click on a red textbox I can't write in because the form disapear to the windows bar....

it s very "weird" because when elements are in other color, these elements behave "correctly"

Can someone tell me where is the problem with the color red?

I hope I was clear enough...

Thanks a lot, best regards

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us anything to work with. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i don t know how describe better. Now when I click on red elements (a button a textbox or whatever back color is red), the program reduce itself ...

Comment: You don't need to describe it more (I understand your problem) but you need to share some code. There's not much anyone here can do without no code to work with. -- Like [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) says: **Restart from scratch**. Make a new application and give some objects red color. If the problem still occurs, post the designer code here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers but it appears that it was a bug...I rebooted my computer today and i don't have this problem anymore...
best regards